Select a tags whose href attributes end with ".ca/" *
Trying to select attributes that have links ending with ".ca" ti highlight them on different color
HTML goes
<li><a href="http://www.google.ca/">Google</a></li> Apple  Wikipedia's Toller Page`
 
Trying the following on CSS:
a:target::after{
content: ".ca/";
background-color: white;`
}
or
a::after{ content: url(.ca); background-color: white;
}`
But cant select it... any suggestions to highlight in white the sites ending in ".ca"?
